# translate .animate() in plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How i translate this code snippet into plain Javascript?

```
const boxWidth = 200

$('.box').css({ left: ( boxWidth * 2) + "px" });

$('.box').animate({
  left: boxWidth + "px"
}, 300);
```

Example attached here:

https://codepen.io/weristsam/pen/RwYaYKG

Comment: There is no direct JS equivalent to the jQuery animate functionality, but [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) can handle the animation when changing a basic style like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to rebuild animate() of jquery

```
function animationLeft(element, start, end) {
  function frame() {
    start++ // update parameters
    element.style.left = left + "px" // show frame
    if (start == end)
      // check finish condition
      clearInterval(id)
  }
  var id = setInterval(frame, 0) // draw every 10ms
}
```

Unfortunately, the the animation time is too slow so i have to use jQuery.

Thanks to all helpers!

Answer (score 1):

This could be an equivalent of what you want to achieve:

```
const boxWidth = 200

const boxEl = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0]
boxEl.style.left = `${boxWidth * 2}px`;
boxEl.animate([{
    transform: `translateX(${-boxWidth}px)`
}], 300);
```

You get the items by class name, and select the first item. You apply properties (`left: boxWidth * 2`) and `animate()`. For animation, you use CSS `transform`, which translates you box for `boxWidth` distance to the left over *300ms*.

Comment: Why switch to `transform` when OP wanted to animate `left`? Also, you will want to `fill: "forwards"` that animation, and to do really the closest to jQuery's, even `easing: "ease-in-out"`. https://jsfiddle.net/wuafLjm2/